# OpenSSL SHA1 Hash doesn't match

Tags: php, shell, openssl

I'm generating a SHA1 hash via OpenSSL via the commandline with the following command:

```
echo -n "test" | openssl dgst -sha1 -sign private.pem | openssl enc -base64
```

The output is:

```
mTuk4MicnS1Xn9BB4wed6pWe62CGDgj6imaOp9f3spiRo/W88WNac7sMkAYl37ruh82mbREbEzsFwCCdhO3MpGh/tyhb+2vx59tta1GTp5Nhb8PlnFL20Zh8QUrv6WrgvsI8z4IPG4KXCJw++7hBQHcnxa8dT5EMn1OW72MumG8=
```

when I execute the same command via PHP with exec() I get a different output:

```
YDGDpc0nC1uaFBO28uepQ/8hMhqoUhXIhqb0UTVCHA2oqWI7PeYyHBB1tmvQ8iqo/ZJzvkNxAruy6T67rdpz/4hyKh6hRxGvYNStteqv/Cn04yiSlgidiHnN2x5aoI6GdE/c0haiE/WmJlFTOcQdPztsQWOk2QUzWdwDmO0OjqE=
```

WHY?

both scripts run via the same user, As the PHP Script is run as "nobody" I have logged in via the shell as nobody and executed it... no dfference

Comment: try to use absolute path. 
`... -sign /path/to/private.pem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the full path fixed the problem!